# why is output shifted in keras model?

Tags: neural-network, keras, deep-learning, lstm, keras-layer

I have following model created in Keras:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv1D(filters=16,kernel_size=4,padding='same', input_shape=(window_size,1))) 
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(128, activation='sigmoid', return_sequences=True))) 
model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(256, activation='sigmoid', return_sequences=True)))
model.add(Dense(128,activation='tanh'))
model.add(Dense(1))
```

The output is:
 [image]

The model seems learned from data but with slighty variation. I don't understand why the output is shifted. What is going wrong with my model? How can I avoid this issue? I've tryed to swap 'tanh' activation by 'sigmoid', but output was still shifted. Any sugestion?

Comment: What are your input features? This might be the reason: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48034625/keras-lstm-predicted-timeseries-squashed-and-shifted/48050810#48050810

Comment: it is a timeserie of shape (N,60,1), where N is greater than 100000 samples.

Comment: curiously, when I swap timestep by features, e.g (N,1,60), the models fits well.