# LSTM categorical crossentropy validation accuracy remains constant

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, time-series, lstm

I've been doing some LSTM network lately, and I'd like to predict a one-hot encoded output (2 classes for now, I already tried with  binary cross entropy and my problem stays the same) given 5 features and 14 lookback steps (batch size is 1). I am using TimeseriesGenerator:

```py
generator = TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_train, train_targets, length=LOOKBACK, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
validation_generator = TimeseriesGenerator(scaled_test, test_targets, length=LOOKBACK, batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
```

Train targets are as following (below, the distribution):

```
array([[1., 0.],
       [0., 1.],
       [1., 0.],
       ...,
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.],
       [1., 0.]], dtype=float32)

0    1  
0.0  1.0    1619
1.0  0.0    1545
dtype: int64
```

and features/`scaled_train` like this:

```
array([[0.22189629, 0.21121072, 0.21790398, 0.19933957, 0.41803716],
       [0.2106806 , 0.21783771, 0.2197984 , 0.2237905 , 0.18050205],
       [0.21885786, 0.21532436, 0.21933581, 0.19678948, 0.16397564],
       ...,
       [0.2104257 , 0.20155003, 0.22193512, 0.20173967, 0.12319585],
       [0.2070304 , 0.19911522, 0.21276043, 0.19141927, 0.11876491],
       [0.19873079, 0.18909128, 0.20785918, 0.19083925, 0.1407046 ]])
```

Test data are formatted the same way.

Model is also super simple:

```py
model = Sequential()

model.add(LSTM(100, input_shape=(LOOKBACK, scaled_train.shape[1])))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Here is the fit output:

[image: Fit output]

Basically, when I'm doing predictions, it returns something `> 0.5` half of the time, `< 0.5` the other half. Fit metrics are just super constant. I also tried to complexify my network with multiple LSTM layers, without success. I also tried to load another to dataset just to try but it didn't change anything. I may be doing something wrong with my generators.

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: What do your features and targets represent? A binary cross-entropy of ~0.6931 is very suspicious - this corresponds to the expected loss of a random predictor (e.g. see [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/341786/calculate-expected-cross-entropy-loss-for-a-random-prediction)). Basically, this happens when your input features are not informative of your target ([this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48034625/keras-lstm-predicted-timeseries-squashed-and-shifted/48050810#48050810) is also relevant).

Comment: have you tried a smaller LSTM network? compare the model parameters to your dataset size and choose a suitable number of nodes. start small and build up to gain some intuition.

Comment: Can you show us how you are preprocessing and scaling your training data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestions:

1. Ensure that you framed the problem correctly. If you have random noise as input dataset or simply values that do not have a pattern, your model cannot learn anything. The absence of a pattern in your dataset and the inability of the data scientist/machine learning engineer of seeing a pattern are different things and this should be taken into consideration. Is your data correctly fed and suitable for your problem? Is it really a classification or a regression problem? If you can answer correctly and easily to all of these questions, proceed to the next steps.
2. Decrease the learning rate. It is possible that, the default learning rate is too high for your problem and the network is simply unable to converge. The default learning rate value for Adam in Keras is `0.001`. Try replacing it with `0.0001` or `0.00001`. A very big learning rate coupled with a batch_size of 1 could contribute to your network's inability to learn/converge.
3. You can also increase the `batch_size` to 8/16 and check if the behaviour changes. You can implement both steps 2 and 3 at the same time, although I would personally start with the 3-rd step at this point to ensure the extent of "help" that is provided for the convergence of the neural network.
4. Are there really enough `14 == timesteps` for your problem? It is likely that changing this parameter will impact your result; if your network struggles to learn, increasing the number of timesteps can be helfpul.

Answer (score 2):

Try maybe to reshape your target data to use `binary_crossentropy`:

```
targets_binary=np.array([np.where(index==1)[0][0] for index in train_targets])
```

So instead of having one-hot encoded vectors like `[[1., 0.],[0., 1.], [1., 0.]]` you will have real label like `[0,1,0]`

With this your last layer should be :

```
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Tried it, unfortunately it didn't improve it. The accuracy stays the same, as the binary_crossentropy loss do. I also tried to complexify the network with multiple LSTM layers but it did not changed anything (aside a learning time way longer of course).

Answer (score 1):

> (batch size is 1)

Try changing that to something like 32.

The following thread includes some reasonable references on the choice of mini-batch size. And also some explanations of why a batch size of 1 can lead to GD not converging.

https://www.reddit.com/r/MachineLearning/comments/8im43v/d_theoretically_does_batch_size1_will_give_the/

Another issue you may want to keep in mind is whether the problem would be solvable by a human... would a human be able to identify some characteristics in the data that would classify some examples as clearly in class 0 vs class 1 ? Is there some function on the sequence that you can think of implementing manually where the output would have meaningful correlation to the labels ? There are scenarios where the input data available is simply not enough to drive a correlation. i.e. the output process is not explainable by the input. For instance if you have a time sequence of prices for a given stock, it is very unlikely that you will be able to predict the next price with any reasonable accuracy given that the process that determines the output is not captured only by these previous data points.

Answer (score 1):

1. The batch size could also be causing this. One-one sample in each batch might not be giving the model's gradients a good direction for optimization and to capture the problem. Try increasing the batch size.
2. If we look at the binary cross-entropy loss values, they seem to be stumbling near the minima. As explained in this post, it could be the cause of higher learning rate, though unlikely
   https://towardsdatascience.com/estimating-optimal-learning-rate-for-a-deep-neural-network-ce32f2556ce0
3. Lastly, considering the accuracy of the binary classifier at the lowest loss value displayed(0.6926) is 0.5095, it seems that the model is really struggling at getting hang of the problem at hand with about 42,602 params. Thus try with a quick and simpler model with flattened 14*5 features and a dense layer with higher batch size. Might give some intuition with clear feature importances.
4. If all of the above aren't helping the loss or accuracy it could because of the below two reasons:

- Noisy data
- We trying to predict something that's not possible to infer from provided input data. Eg. trying to predict if the person is male or female given their geographical location for a lookback of 14 days. Irrespective of how we featurise this training set there will be hardly any correlation between location and gender. (very similar to something suggested by Pedro)